# Windows Uninstalls Program at Runtime

Tags: windows, windows-10

I had 2 programs on my computer that I can no longer use:

- GameMaker Studio 1.4 http://yoyogames.com
- Resilio Sync https://www.resilio.com/individuals/

I install the program and it installs just fine. When I start the program it starts, but then it automatically closes. When I try to open it again it says the it is not installed.

When I go to `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` it is there, but if I try to uninstall it there it also says that it is not installed.

I have scanned my computer with `AVG` and `Windows Defender` and neither of them found any viruses.

My search on Google shows many people seem to have the issue where programs are uninstalled after an upgrade, but that is not the case here. Here it is when I attempt to execute a program.

Comment: What, if anything, is logged in the Windows Event Logs when this happens (particularly the Application log)?

Comment: In the `Event Viewer` I am looking at `Windows Logs > Application` I assume this is the right place, and if so, nothing gets logged.

Comment: That's correct.  Have a look at the System log as well.

Comment: Nothing happens here either. (I cleared both logs and and reinstalled)

Answer (score -1):

This makes me think of either an antivirus or some security software that deletes some files like those executable. Check in your antivirus to see if it did delete. Since you got some free antivirus, just uninstall it, repeat the installation process of those 2 apps and try again without any AV and disable windows defender temporarly...see if that works.

thats exactly what happens when i plug a usb drive with produkey on it hehe

Comment: That didn't work. No change.